# Launcing Applications with Custom URI on Android

Tags: android, uri

I am developing an application on Android and my application needs to be launched whenever a URI like (myscheme://mydata) is clicked on an SMS or Email.

I am using following filter for my app :

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="secture"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

However on emails and SMS messages, my URIs with the form of myscheme://mydata show up as
regular tests and i cannot click on them to launch my application.

Thanks for help

**Edit :** 
I found out that Linkfy class does something similar however it modifies your own text into links. What I need is modifying other applications such as Email and SMS. So is it possible to change another applications Linkfy?

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible to change another applications Linkfy?

No, sorry.

Instead of `myscheme://mydata`, use `http://mydomain/mypath`. You can create an `<intent-filter>` for this so that you get control instead of the browser, and the resulting URLs will be friendlier to other apps. As a bonus, you can put a real Web page at that URL, so if somebody who does not have your app winds up with your URL (e.g., forwarded email), the URL will still work..